# Recursive function to find all paths to a specific target

Tags: python, recursion, path, longest-path

I need to find the longest path to a given target. The data is a dictionary of ids with the value being a list of all ids that point to that id. Also worth noting that each Id can only point to one other id.

I tried to write a recursive function that will go through each possible path, and store each unique path option to another list, from which I will find the longest path.

```
def create(main, vec, id):
    if (id not in INFO):
        return(main, vec, id)
    else:
        for source in INFO[id]:
            vec.append(source)
            main.append(vec)
            main, vec, id = create(main, vec, source)
        return main,vec,id
```

and longest function

```
def longest(main):
    longest = 0
    long_list = 0
    for list in main:
        if len(list) > longest:
            long_list = list
            longest = len(list)
    return long_list
```

when doing

```
INFO = {
    'D4': ['B2','B6'],
    'B6': ['D3'],
    'D3': ['F1','A2'],
    'A2': ['G8'],
    'A1': ['C3'],
    'B2': ['E3','A1']}
main, vec, id = create([],[],'D4')
print(longest(main))
```

I get main to have paths that stack on top of eachother. How would I fix the code so the paths don't stack.
I hope to get main to look something like

```
[['B2'],
['B2','E3'],
['B2','A1'],
['B2','A1','C3'],
['B6'],
['B6','D3'],
['B6','D3','F1'],
['B6','D3','A2'],
['B6','D3','A2','G8']]
```

**EDIT:**

Changed line `main, vec, id = create(main,[],'D4')` to `main, vec, id = create([],[],'D4')` to clarify that `main` is a list of lists.

Comment: What is `main` in `create(main,[],'D4')`?

Comment: main is a list of lists. its the structure that should contain all the paths

Comment: yeh the first time it is an empty list (unless I want to include the original target in the list also, then i wud send [['D4']])

Comment: Just saw you edit, thanks. I do not quite understand your expected output. Could you please explain its structure?

Comment: My expected output would be a list of lists, which are the paths to get to the target beacon. But in this case due to implementation its backwards. So for example line ['B6','D3','F1'] means that a path would from F1 -> D3 -> B6 -> target (D4). My goal is to get all possible paths to the target, and find what is the longest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the recursive property of your approach it is hard to keep track of the path between the current node and the starting node (root).

However, when you are only interested in the longest path, it certainly links the root and a leave (these are the nodes which do not have a link to any other node).

In the following code, when reaching one of the leaves, i.e. when `currentNode not in INFO` is `true`, I travel the way up and recording the path till reaching the root.

```
def create(pathListRef, currentNode, rootNode):
    # pathListRef is the reference to the list containing the paths between all leaves and the root.
    # currentNode holds the current node, e.g. "D3"
    # rootNode holds reference to the root node, i.e. "D4"

    if (currentNode not in INFO):
        # We have reached on of the leaves

        reverseNode = currentNode
        # reverseNode is used to keep track of at which node we are when traveling back to the root.

        path = []
        # holds the relative path between the leave and reverseNode

        while reverseNode is not rootNode:
            # As long as we have not reached the root

            path.insert(0, reverseNode)
            # Prepend (like append, but at the start of the list) the reverseNode to the relative path

            reverseNode = list(INFO.keys())[[i for i,x in enumerate(list(INFO.values())) if reverseNode in x][0]]
            # Get the node linked with the reverseNode and move forward to that one. In essence get the key, where the value contains (since it is a list) the reverseNode.

        pathListRef.append(path)
        # We are at the root, so add the relative path to the final paths list
        return

    # This is only executed when we are not at the leave yet (since we return when we are at a leave)
    for source in INFO[currentNode]:
        create(pathListRef, source, rootNode)
```

It is used as follows:

```
myList = []
startNode = "D4"
create(myList, startNode, startNode)
print(myList)  # -> [['B2', 'E3'], ['B2', 'A1', 'C3'], ['B6', 'D3', 'F1'], ['B6', 'D3', 'A2', 'G8']]
```

And by using your `longest()` function you get:

```
print(longest(myList))  # -> ['B6', 'D3', 'A2', 'G8']
```

Btw, it is possible to shorten your `longest()` function to the following one. Furthermore, this code also returns multiple paths if there is not only one longest.

```
def longest(main):
    return [x for x in main if len(x) == max([len(x) for x in main])]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will use this approach :)